# Jquery after click and load it copy and paste part of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, volt

I am here with a good problem that I don't know how to fix it. I was putting some javascript inside my volt file and when I asked to click it works and load the page but the problem is that also copy and past part of my `<head>` files and part of my bootstrap navbar menu `<nav>`.

Bootstrap Menu code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li {% if view.url == '/' %}
                        class="active"
                    {% endif %}
                ><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">DaizCode</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <?php

                $this->view->url = $this->router->getRewriteUri();
             ?>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']) == false) { ?>
                <li {% if view.url == '/about' %}
                        class="active"
                    {% endif %}
                ><a href="/about" class="about">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li {% if view.url == 'auth/login' %}
                  class="active"
                {% endif %}
              ><a href="auth/login" class="login">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li {% if view.url == 'auth/register' %}
                  class="active"
                {% endif %}
              ><a href="auth/register">Register</a>
              </li>
              <?php } else { ?>
                <li {% if view.url == '/auth/dashboard' %}
                            class="active"
                        {% endif %}
                    ><a href="/auth/dashboard" title="Dashboard" class="dashboard"><img src="http://www.daizcode.com/img/activity-icon.png" /></a>
                </li>
                <li {% if view.url == '/auth/dashboard/learn' %}
                    class="active"
                  {% endif %}
                ><a href="/auth/dashboard/learn" title="Learn" class="learn"><img src="http://www.daizcode.com/img/learn-icon.png" /></a>
                </li>
                <li {% if view.url == 'auth/dashboard/discussions' %}
                    class="active"
                  {% endif %}
                ><a href="auth/dashboard/discussions" title="Discussions" class="conv"><img src="http://www.daizcode.com/img/conv-icon.png" /></a>
                </li>
                <li {% if view.url == 'auth/dashboard/notifications' %}
                    class="active"
                  {% endif %}
                ><a href="auth/dashboard/notifications" title="Notifications" class="notifications"><img src="http://www.daizcode.com/img/globe-icon.png" /></a>
                </li>
                <li {% if view.url == 'auth/dashboard/inbox' %}
                    class="active"
                  {% endif %}
                ><a href="auth/dashboard/inbox" title="Inbox" class="inbox"><img src="http://www.daizcode.com/img/inbox-icon.png" /></a>
                </li>
              <?php } ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
       {{ content() }}
```

`{{ content() }}` is part of the volt template where it goes pick the other pages immediately to show it. 
I have some PHP so I can show different menu after the user be on or not.

Here it is the **nav file** (**nav.volt**) code:

```
<input type="text" class="user-login" name="user-login" placeholder="Username..." />
<input type="password" class="password-login" name="pwd" placeholder="Password..." />
<a href="#" name="close" class="close">X</a>
```

Here I let you my volt page (script part):

```
{{ javascript_include('/js/jquery-3.1.1.js') }}
{{ javascript_include('/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}
{{ javascript_include('/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".login").click(function() {
    $(".navbar-right").load("auth/login/nav");
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Here I can show you the image where you see the inspect of the page, and it is inspecting after the click of class `.login` which is in bootstrap navbar. The code I want to show on it is there after the red rectangle. 
What I want to know is how can I remove what's inside of the rectangle. See the image below.

[Google Chrome Inspect of the problem I said above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXFR4.png)

[Updated image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i982W.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to fetch specific part of the file ,

This would load the input elements and a tag after input element with out loading nav or any other tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".login").click(function() {
    $(".navbar-right").load("auth/login/nav input,input+a");
    return false;
  });

</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This will just pull the nav tag from the file and not copy head section

Comment: No, I thought you mean the menu bar, but i will update again with the nav file.

Comment: It's below the bootstrap menu, the nav file.

Comment: umm very weird O.o i tried it with a test page on my end it worked, i am curious what happens when you use just input tag ? like remove ",input+a"

Comment: still blank, i don't know if it's because of the phalcon volt template or not. Or if it is because of other thing...

Comment: if I let without "input, input+a" it copy part of the head like:
`<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">`

Comment: after clicking it appears inside of `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">` the `::before` and `::after` if I use the "input, input+a" . Isn't loading the page...